# Prevent hibernate from selecting children when updating its parent?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

### The Problem

When I update my parent class, hibernate selects all its child before triggering the update.
This only happens when we added new children that are not persistent in the database yet.
Hibernate selects those children one by one, which is very... very slow.

Batching is already enabled and working for normal inserts, updates and removals.
I gave the child a version, which hibernates ignores somehow.

```
select * from identity...
select * from identity...
select * from identity...
select * from identity...
insert .... into identity...
update chunk set ....
```

### Question

Is there a way to either make hibernate batch those selects or to implement some other mechanic in which hibernate simply checks the added child if its new without selecting it from the database first?

I basically want to get rid of those "one by one" selects. Would be glad for any help I can get.

### My Classes

When I update chunk which contains multiple identities that are not yet in the database ( inChunk )... it tries to determine if they are in the database which results in one select for each child to filter those children that are need to get inserted... how do I prevent those many selects? I still want to keep the cascading.

```java
@Entity
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
@SQLInsert(sql = "insert into identity(tag, typeID, id, version) values(?,?,?,?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id = VALUES(id), tag = values(tag), typeID = values(typeID), version = values(version)")
@SelectBeforeUpdate(value = false)
public class Identity extends Component {

    @Id public long id;
    public String tag;
    public String typeID;

    @Version public long version;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "chunk", uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"x", "y"})}, indexes = {@Index(columnList = "x,y")})
@Access(value = AccessType.FIELD)
@SelectBeforeUpdate(false)
public class Chunk extends HibernateComponent {

    public int x;
    public int y;
    public Date createdOn;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    @BatchSize(size = 50)
    public Set<Identity> inChunk = new LinkedHashSet<>();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unidirectional one-to-many association - is not good practice. I would recommend to define the many-to-one association in the `Identity` class, then add the `mappedBy` attribute to the `@OneToMany` annotation on the `inChunk` field, and then fetch `Chunk.inChunk` association before add new children.

```
@Entity
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
@SQLInsert(sql = "insert into identity(tag, typeID, id, version) values(?,?,?,?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id = VALUES(id), tag = values(tag), typeID = values(typeID), version = values(version)")
@SelectBeforeUpdate(value = false)
public class Identity extends Component {

    @Id public long id;
    public String tag;
    public String typeID;

    @Version public long version;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "chunk_id") // I suppose the Chunk entity has id
    public Chunk chunk;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "chunk", uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"x", "y"})}, indexes = {@Index(columnList = "x,y")})
@Access(value = AccessType.FIELD)
@SelectBeforeUpdate(false)
public class Chunk extends HibernateComponent {

    public int x;
    public int y;
    public Date createdOn;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "chunk")
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    @BatchSize(size = 50)
    public Set<Identity> inChunk = new LinkedHashSet<>();
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! The problem here is that identity is... my "root" of the database, it should not contain chunks at all. But im gonna try out adding the mapped by.

Comment: Identity in DB should contain the foreign key to the chunk. How do you implement the reference between identity and chunk now? In the DB, not in Java.

Comment: Well thats also not possible... in this specific case the chunk should point to identities. But never the other way around. I basically have a chunk table, a chunk_identity mapping table and a table of all identities. Chunks and identities getting combined in that mapping table ^^

Comment: Ok, I understand. But I have no experience with unidirectional one-to-many, so I don't know a correct solution for your case. I would try to fetch `Chunk.inChunk` association before add a new child. You may do it using entity graph or `JOIN FETCH` in JPQL.

Comment: I implemented some automation for inserting, updating and destroying entities... such a fine grain control is also not possible in my case :/ I think i isolated the issue, its the cascade update mechanic. I insert entities that are not in the database yet and each one of them already have an id... hibernate does not like that and throws selects. But still no idea how to prevent this

Comment: Maybe you should use native SQL queries?